# Is it possible to push to a separate repository from within the work-tree of a bare repository?

Tags: git

I have a central bare repository on my dev. web server that I use.

I have a post-receive hook that sets the work-tree to be a different directory, and all of my files are pushed there.  Works peachy-keen.  Keeps the git repository files separate from the actual code.

So, essentially, it's set up like this:

```
Git repo directory:
    /git/project.git

GIT_WORK_TREE:
    /var/www/project
```

I'd like to use my work-tree and set up another repository that pushes to a live server from this dev. one.

I'd like to do this so I can just push the finished files up to the live server without all of the extra tools and stuff, like my SASS and whatnot.

Could I just go into `/var/www/project` and `git init`?  Will that break anything with my current repo?

Is there a better or known way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you push from the original /git/project.git repo? You have to understand that push does not push the working files, but commits, trees, blobs and refs only.

Comment: Ahh -- well, I guess I wanted to set it up in a way that I'd be pushing to the dev server, testing, and the pushing to the live server if everything looks good - not push to both at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I just go into /var/www/project and git init? Will that break anything with my current repo?

No it won't break anyhting.

As long as your hook does set `GIT_DIR` to `/git/project.git` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` to `/var/www/project` to checkout your files, the .git you would create within `/var/www/project` would be ignored.

Although I would create that repo outside of `/var/www/project` to be on the safe side.

The only risk is one of de-synchronization between the worktree of the `/git/project.git` and the one of your second git repo.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the information.  I'll let this question incubate before selecting an answer to see if anyone else has something to say.